# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '('.' ERROR

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create Update function for my windows applications for some reason it's not working and come up with this error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '('.'"  Any suggestions?

```
    private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

            if (txt_BranchID.Text != "" && txt_BranchName.Text != "" && txt_BranchAddress.Text != "" && txt_Telephone.Text != "")
            {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Update BInfo(BranchID, BranchName, BranchAddress, Telephone) values(@BranchID, @BranchName, @BranchAddress, @Telephone)", con);
            con.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchName", txt_BranchName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchAddress", txt_BranchAddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", txt_Telephone.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record updated Successfully");
                con.Close();
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax for update query is different than Insert query. It should look like:

```
update BInfo
SET 
    BranchName = @BranchName, 
    BranchAddress = @BranchAddress, 
    Telephone = @Telephone
    where BranchID = @BranchID
```

and there should also be a `where` clause specifying which Branch information we are going to update so at last line put `where`

in string form in the code it would be like:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Update BInfo
SET 
    BranchName = @BranchName, 
    BranchAddress = @BranchAddress, 
    Telephone = @Telephone
    where BranchID = @BranchID",con);
```

Also `@BranchId` is missing in your command parameters, it would be needed there:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchID", "branchId here");
```

Comment: @RusNikita96 If it worked for you, can you mark it as Answer so it won't show up in unanswered questions. Thanks.

Comment: @ThimmuLanka Thanks for your help and letting me know. I will defiantly post an answer right now. It was my first question in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Answer for my question.

private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
            if (txt_BranchID.Text != "" && txt_BranchName.Text != "" && txt_BranchAddress.Text != "" && txt_Telephone.Text != "")
            {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update BInfo set BranchID=@BranchID,Branchname=@BranchName, BranchAddress=@BranchAddress, Telephone=@Telephone where BranchID=@BranchId", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchID", txt_BranchID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchName", txt_BranchName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchAddress", txt_BranchAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telephone", txt_Telephone.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record updated Successfully");
            con.Close();
            DisplayData();
            ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
            }
    }
```